# Need to rescue ubuntu without mess

Tags: grub2, 13.04, grubrescue

I usually play with OS and always use dual boot (win,ubuntu). So the grub problem is more obvious, At my first usage of Ubuntu I found it very difficult to restore grub. Live CD method always frustrated.

Luckily I found an image of Ubuntu grub rescue (Automagic grub or something i forgot its name) that was very helpful, It simply detects Ubuntu and I can re-enter if some grub prob occurs.

And the tough time for me now is I lost that CD. I can't even find exactly that image there are many like that but I found difficult to do it.

I installed Windows after installing Ubuntu. So grub is gone and I want it back. Please suggest me a neat way to do it. (it would be better if anyone found the same CD I used).

Answer (score 0):

You can try booting your computer with **live Ubuntu CD/USB** and then install and run **boot-repair**:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Also, if you regularly backup your system (e.g. Ubuntu partition also storing the grub bootloader) using **Clonezilla**, you can easily restore your system after even more complicated problems in the future.